# mysql recursive self join intersecting columns

Tags: mysql, join, recursion, intersection, self

Say I have a starting table (derived) that is like this...

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| UsergroupID | ParentID | PermissionIDs              |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1           | 0        | 1                          |
| 1           | 0        | 2                          |
| 1           | 0        | 3                          |
| 1           | 0        | 4                          |
| 1           | 0        | 5                          |
| 1           | 0        | 6                          |
| 2           | 1        | 1                          |
| 2           | 1        | 8                          |
| 2           | 1        | 9                          |
| 3           | 1        | 3                          |
| 3           | 1        | 8                          |
| 3           | 1        | 2                          |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

and I'm looking to get an ending result set that looks like this

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| UsergroupID | ParentID | PermissionID               |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1           | 0        | 1                          |
| 1           | 0        | 2                          |
| 1           | 0        | 3                          |
| 1           | 0        | 4                          |
| 1           | 0        | 5                          |
| 1           | 0        | 6                          |
| 2           | 1        | 1                          |
| 3           | 1        | 3                          |
| 3           | 1        | 2                          |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

which is basically doing a recursive lookup on the parent id and then intersecting (inner joining) the values in the PermissionID column  .  So a child can never have more permissions then a parent.

I've looked up stuff on user defined functions (thinking I could wrap a udf around a column and have it intersect recursively based on a parent id) but that didn't get me very far.  The only thing I can really think of is not doing it db side but doing it with server side code.

Solarflare -- Here is what I just tried using your script... this worked!

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE prcPermCleanup5()
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE table1 (usergroupID INT, parentID INT, StoreID INT)  ENGINE=MEMORY; 
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
(1,0,1),
(1,0,2),
(1,0,3),
(1,0,4),
(2,1,1),
(2,1,2),
(2,0,5),
(3,2,2),
(3,2,7),
(4,1,1),
(4,1,2),
(5,4,1),
(5,4,8),
(6,2,1),
(6,2,6);
  REPEAT
     DELETE entry.*
    FROM table1 entry
    LEFT JOIN table1 parent
    ON entry.parentID = parent.usergroupID
    AND entry.`StoreID` = parent.StoreID
    WHERE parent.usergroupID IS NULL
    AND NOT entry.parentID = 0;
   UNTIL row_count() = 0 END REPEAT;  
  SELECT * FROM table1;
END $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Are you open to normalize your data and don't have an array of permissions in the column PermissionsID and instead use another table that lists that permissions? Most problems get more complicated with unnormalized data, this is a good example. And you may want to use nested sets, although you probably can use the tree too (if you repeat your function for recursion)

Comment: I'm open to changing up the data format and my second table example (3rd table in the original post) is one that displays the permissions as rows and not as a concatenated column.  This "table" is actually a derived table as well.

Comment: Ah ok, yes, that's better, I think I missed the point of the "starting table". So you have your table: do you want to "clean it up" (delete or mark the "wrong" entries) or do you want to keep the "wrong" entries and have a query that returns that cleaner list? I think both cannot be done in one single step, but the 1st one would be a query that you would have to execute n times (n=depth of your tree - 1 or until nothing changes), the 2nd one would, I guess, require a temp table (you can do that in a stored procedure/udf).

Comment: Hi Solarflare,  I'd like to "clean it up" so the only thing I've got for each usergroup are the relevant permission groups given the permissions of the parents.  I'm going to clean up my original post a little more to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do that in one single query (unless maybe under some special conditions), but you can just repeat a clean-up query to do a recursion that way.

If your cleanup is a one-time thing, you can just run the following query several times until nothing changes anymore (you need at most `depth of tree - 1` runs):

```
delete entry.*
from table1 entry
left join table1 parent
on entry.parentID = parent.usergroupID
and entry.permissionIDs = parent.permissionIDs
where parent.usergroupID is null
and not entry.parentID = 0;
```

You can automate that repetition in a procedure, e.g.

```
delimiter $$
create procedure prcPermCleanup()
begin
  repeat
    delete entry.*
    from table1 entry
    left join table1 parent
    on entry.parentID = parent.usergroupID
    and entry.permissionIDs = parent.permissionIDs
    where parent.usergroupID is null
    and not entry.parentID = 0;
  until row_count() = 0 end repeat;  
end $$
delimiter ;

call prcPermCleanup;
```

As a side-note:

You might want to normalize your data, e.g. have a seperate table for your permissions:

```
table permissions: usergroupID | permissionID

table tree: usergroupID | parentID
```

In your current table, you have the same information (the information, which `parentID` is the parent of a `usergroupID`) several times in your table, aka denormalized. A practical consequence of that would be that you could have two different `parentID` for the same `usergroupID`, which would usually be undefined in a tree.

Comment: Thanks Solarflare.  I'll give this a shot and get back asap!

Comment: Hi Solarflare.  I gave this a shot and see that it works on the initial pass (first run) but after that it doesn't look like it deletes anything else.  Trying to debug now.... looks like the parentId in the where statement might need to change every time through.

Comment: @Josh Can you add an example that doesn't get cleaned up? The code will stop as soon as it's cleaned up, it doesn't necessarily needs n-1 runs (it's just the max), so maybe it has already completed after first run. But maybe I missed something.

Comment: Hi Solarflare.  I just went in to create a smaller example of what I'm trying to do and your stuff worked great.  So, first of all, sorry about saying it didn't work.  It must have been operator error on my side when I was modifying what you had to work with my real data.    running out of room for my example.  I'll post what I just tried using your stored proc that worked in the original post

Comment: so I just tried this again with my "real" data... about 30k rows of parent child relationships and I've got results.... Kinda slow though, running about 9 seconds .  Gonna experiment with speeding this up if possible.  Maybe adding some indexes to my temp table

Comment: just ran this with indexes on the temp table and this puppy is cooking now.  Went from 9 seconds to .3 seconds which will work !  Thanks so much Solarflare

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this isn't necessarily the answer ... but in the following setup I'm finding that I'm getting the correct table info back.  This example works under the assumption that I know (and can pass in a max depth and grouping relationships (which I *believe* I can although the grouping relationships might be an issue when I actually try this with "real" data).  Anyway, this is what I have

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS joshTestTable;
CREATE TABLE joshTestTable (id INT, parent INT, store INT) ENGINE=MEMORY; 
INSERT INTO joshTestTable VALUES
(1,0,1),
(1,0,2),
(1,0,3),
(1,0,4),
(2,1,1),
(2,1,2),
(2,0,5),
(3,2,2),
(3,2,7),
(4,1,1),
(4,1,2),
(5,4,1),
(5,4,8),
(6,2,1),
(6,2,6);


SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM joshTestTable p
    WHERE p.parent = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.* FROM joshTestTable p
    LEFT JOIN joshTestTable c 
    ON p.id = c.parent
    AND p.store = c.store
    AND c.parent=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.* FROM joshTestTable p
    LEFT JOIN joshTestTable c 
    ON p.id = c.parent
    AND p.store = c.store
    AND c.parent IN (2,4) ) outter WHERE id IS NOT NULL;
```

I'm still not super hot on this as a solution because of all the known stuff I'll need to pass in to a stored proc to automate this .  I get real close by just doing left joins to the tree depth but in that case I get a table with a bunch column sets that I need to somehow quazi-pivot.  For instance.

```
SELECT * FROM joshTestTable p
LEFT JOIN joshTestTable c 
ON p.id = c.parent
AND p.store = c.store
LEFT JOIN joshTestTable gc
ON c.id = gc.parent
AND c.store = gc.store
WHERE p.parent = 0;
```

This end up giving me all the info but it's just in a format that I don't think I can use.  It gives me a table like this...

```
id  parent  store   id  parent  store   id  parent  store
1      0    1       2     1       1     6      2    1
1      0    1       4     1       1     5      4    1
1      0    2       2     1       2     3      2    2
1      0    2       4     1       2     NULL    NULL    NULL
1      0    3       NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1      0    4       NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2      0    5       NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

and in the end I'm looking for this (which is what my first query does give me)...

```
id  parent  store
1   0       1
1   0       2
1   0       3
1   0       4
2   0       5
2   1       1
2   1       2
3   2       2
4   1       1
4   1       2
5   4       1
6   2       1
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if your goal here is to have just one query that just selects the correct entries. In that case: yes, the first problem is that you have to know the depth. The second more severe thing is this will not work recursively: If you have entries (1,0,1), (2,1,2), (3,2,2), it will give you (1,0,1), (3,2,2), because for (3,2,2) it will look up one step above and finds (2,1,2), but doesn't "know" that this entry will actually not be in the final resultset, because (1,0,2) does not exist. As I said in my answer, I doubt it is possible to do that recursive lookup in just one query.

Comment: ah yeah, you are totally right on the not working recursively.  I guess my goal was to get to some form of end data that I can join to another table on the id and store columns as quickly as possible (execution time-wise) .  In the end the output set didn't really have to be in the form I originally gave in my example, but I did need to somehow get to the place where I could have those parent child relationships represented in some way that I could tease out a join to the other table.